# scala 2.12.1 ClassNotFoundException Product$class

Tags: scala

I recently updated scala from v2.11.8 to 2.12.1 and got a CNF exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
```

I saw the class is shipped by scala-library.jar. 
The error happens when running a scalatest (the project is still at a very early stage so I have only tests).

Do you have any idea? I found nothing on the release notes.

Comment: Are you using `sbt`? If so, what version ?

Comment: No, I am not using sbt.
I tend to agree with Alexej that I have a version mismatch. Some of the jars I am using are for 2.11. scalatest is for example for 2.11 but a 2.12 version is not available yet and I should build from sources or otherwise wait to switch to 2.12 until it is better supported.

Comment: You should be using sbt.

Comment: Why do you think Scalatest isn't available for 2.12? It is: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I took the new version of ScalaTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In particular, trait implementations are no longer provided in classes named with the `$class` suffix. You'll find the notice about "trait encoding" in the release notes.

Probably you want to use sbt or ammonite if experimenting with any dependencies besides built-ins. One day they will have a tidy "platform" to help you.

```
$ cat notraitclass.scala

package notraitclass

trait T {
  def t: Int = 42
}
$ scalac211 notraitclass.scala
$ ls notraitclass
T.class  T$class.class
$ rm -rf notraitclass
$ scalac notraitclass.scala
$ ls notraitclass
T.class
```

Answer (score 12):

libraries are not binary compatible between 2.11 and 2.12, most likely one of your libraries has to be recompiled with scala 2.12

Comment: Great! I thought it were the same... and wondered about the curious exception